# How to change equation numbering globally?

Tags: equations, numbering

I would like to change equation numbering like: (1a) (1b) (1c). How should I do this? My code is like this:

```
\begin{equation}
first equation with number(1a)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
first equation with number(1b)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
first equation with number(1c)
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should make clear what the fixed number means: is it the section/chapter number or is it the “global number” of the set of equations? In the latter case, follow the link shown by Werner; otherwise `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection\alph{equation}}` is the way to go.

Comment: Do you want to do this globally, or do you need subeqations?

Comment: I want to do this globally. Thanks for your help